# C# DevExpress - How to link lookupEdit Column data in GridView to GridView column[0] from MySqlDB

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have LookUpEdit in a columns of Gridview. but the data were not link to Columns["ID"] in each row. How to do it?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
                string query = "SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID = '" + gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "ID").ToString() + "' ";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, MySqlDBCon.con);
                if (MySqlDBCon.con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    MySqlDBCon.con.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter oda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                oda.Fill(dt);
                RepositoryItemLookUpEdit riLookup = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
                riLookup.DataSource = dt;
                riLookup.ValueMember = "ID";
                riLookup.DisplayMember = "Position";
                riLookup.PopulateColumns();
                riLookup.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
                riLookup.Columns["ClientID"].Visible = false;
                gridView1.Columns["CustomerContact"].ColumnEdit = riLookup;

                //LookUpEdit - BestFitMode
                riLookup.BestFitMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.BestFitMode.BestFitResizePopup;
                riLookup.SearchMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.SearchMode.AutoComplete;
            }
```

[Click Here to Show Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buUEC.png)

As images above, every cell has shows exactly the same data. It's linked to cells[0]

Answer (score 0):

RepositoryItems are shared for every cell in a column. This means they will all share the same data source. If you need a single cell in a column to use a different editor or an editor with a different data source, it is necessary to create it at runtime by handling the GridView's [CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event) event.

In your case, the CustomRowCellEdit you create will retrieve the current ID value, perform your query, create an instance of a RepositoryItemLookUpEdit and assign its data source to the results of the query.

You may also wish to review the [Modify and Validate Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/753/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Editing-and-Validation/Modify-and-Validate-Cell-Values) documentation for further examples.